# Where to get this browser info?

Tags: asp-classic

I'm working on some logging functionality for a website, and I need to update a table with information about the users' browser info. The table was created a while ago by someone else, and I have no idea where they were getting this info. Does anyone recognize this? (each line is a single row)

```
Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; GTB0.0; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; InfoPath.1; .NET CLR 2.0.50727)
Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; FunWebProducts; FBSMTWB; SIMBAR={8FCFDD51-4B26-489E-A39E-AB2744B
Java/1.6.0_06
Opera/9.80 (Windows NT 5.1; U; en) Presto/2.5.24 Version/10.53
BlackBerry9630/4.7.1.61 Profile/MIDP-2.0 Configuration/CLDC-1.1 VendorID/105
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's in the HTTP [User-Agent header](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.43).

Comment: Cool that's exactly what I needed. Will accept answer in 10 minutes.

Answer (score 5):

Here is the code you would use in ASP.

```
 Dim sAgent: sAgent = Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_USER_AGENT")
```